# Doclava - How to generate versioned xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, documentation, javadoc

I am using Doclava for android documentation. I want to use the API versioning feature for which I need to set [-since version.xml name](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/CommandLineArguments#-since_version.xml__name) in the ant task. How do I generate these versioned xml files? [They look like this.](http://doclava.googlecode.com/svn/static/api/android-8.xml)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "unclear", as the provided example link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the generated documentation.

Go to reference/current.xml ..that is the xml you're looking for